# Why is there is difference in number of instructions executed by a program when it is running under GDB?

Tags: arm, gdb, pthreads, glibc, performance-monitor

I am using ARM PMU counter to count the number of instructions executed between two system calls by a process. Particularly I am using "INST_RETIRED" event to count the number of instructions executed by a process in user mode. [Reference: ARMv7 R/A Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference/index.html). The number of instructions is consistent if either I am running a program in free mode or under GDB. The problem arises when I try to create a thread using pthread_create. The number of instructions executed by the same program between two system calls mprotect and clone (both executed by the function pthread_create) is different when I run it under GDB. That means that the user program is executing some different code when it is running under a debugger, may be in the library, libpthread. I have seen the source code of pthread_create but could not find anything related to trace/debug flags. Copuld anybody please guide me where is then this ambuguity coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have seen the source code of pthread_create but could not find anything related to trace/debug flags

There is in fact such code [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_create.c;h=caaf07c134c5c79e8137683ab2be4083b6bf50ca;hb=HEAD#l486) and [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_create.c;h=caaf07c134c5c79e8137683ab2be4083b6bf50ca;hb=HEAD#l593). `report_events` is set to true only when running under debugger.

Comment: Since I was using an older version of Glibc(2.17). I could not find this check in pthread_create.c. It turns out that such check on thread creation was in file createthread.c  in function `create_thread (struct pthread *pd, const struct pthread_attr *attr,...)` for my particular version of glibc. Thanks for leading to the right path!

Comment: Please allow me to ask one more thing,  Why pthread_create is defined in glibc, Should'nt it be part of libpthread source code?

Comment: @JinaLee GLIBC consists of some 200+ libraries: `libc.so.6`, `libpthread.so.0`, `ld-linux.so.2`, `libdl.so.2`, etc. Implementing `libpthread` without deep integration with `libc` internals is pretty much impossible.